# Does ethereum wallets have HD addresses like Bitcoin? How do I generate my own seed?

Tags: hd-wallets

Bitcoin has HD wallet addresses where you can generate a 12 word seed which generates all the addresses moving forward. Does Ethereum have something like this in the mist wallet? How can someone get the same affect of an HD seed where I can just write down?